# Blog post url should be same as websites bread crumb navigation

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite, permalinks

Can we get a permalink which will mimic the website's bread crumb navigation.

Our current blog post link is http://skillbase.in/2016/01/19/node-js-php/

Can we avoid the date to appear in the url and change it to something like the following

http://skillbase.in/blog/node-js-php/

(or)

http://skillbase.in/node-js-php/

Comment: Yes, you can. It's in the settings.

Answer (score 0):

in wordpress control panel go to `Settings → Permalinks`

then there is many options . for example if you choose **Post name** it will look like this `http://www.sample.com/sample-post`

more info [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Permalinks_Screen)